# SwiftUI: Close modal sheet programmatically from a function inside an Environment Object

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, environmentobject, modal-view

I've a main view that displays a modal sheet. As I've multiple modals, I use enum and State to control [which sheet is presented.](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-deal-with-modal-views-a-k-a-sheets-with-swiftui-5c4cca7862d6)

```
@State var activeSheet: Sheet?
```

Inside my MainView:

```
    Button(action: {
        activeSheet = .settings
    }, label: {
        Text(“Button”)
    })

   .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { sheet in
        switch sheet {
        case .info:
          InfoView()
        case .settings:
          SettingsView()
        }
      }
```

SettingsView:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MainModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Action") {
            model.myFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

In my InfoView-sheet I have a button that calls a function inside an EnvironmentObject. **How do I dismiss the sheet once the function has completed in the EnvironmentObject?**

Every view is linked to the same EnvironmentObject btw.

Thanks!

Comment: ImageSizeImageSizead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending for which min iOS version you are deploying, you have two options:

If your minimum iOS version is <= iOS 14, in both `InfoView` and `SettingsView` use system environment `\.presentationMode`.

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MainModel
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") {

            /// ... Do something here prior to dismissing the sheet.
            model.MyFunction(email: email, password: password) {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On your minimum iOS version is iOS 15, in both `InfoView` and `SettingsView` use system environment `\.dismiss`.

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MainModel
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") {

            /// ... Do something here prior to dismissing the sheet.
            model.MyFunction(email: email, password: password) {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And `MainModel` class:

```
class MainModel: ObservableObject {
    func myFunction(email: String, password: String, onSuccess: (() -> Void)? = nil) {         
        auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] result, error in
            if result == nil, error != nil {
                 self?.showAlert = true
            } else {
                 guard result != nil, error == nil else { return }
                 /* Success */
                 self?.signedIn = true
                 onSuccess?()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Alternative solution:**

If your minimum deployment target is >= iOS 14, you can listen to changes of your environment object properties like this:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MainModel
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") {
            model.MyFunction(email: email, password: password)
        }
        .onChange(of: model.signedIn) { signedIn in
            if signedIn {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, in my case I would like to dismiss the sheet only once the function from the EnvironmentObject has been completed. 

struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MainModel

    var body: some View {
        Button("Action") {
             model.MyFunction()
        }
    }
}

How would I do this?

Comment: What is `model.MyFunction()`? If it is synchronous function, then just call `dismiss()` after you call `model.MyFunction()`. If it is asynchronous function, then you MUST have the POSSIBILITY TO KNOW when it completes. I.e. you must have a completion handler as a parameter. Do you have it?

Comment: Here is the function. If the function returns an error, the modal view should stay open, if it succeeds then the modal view should be closed.

func myFunction(email: String, password: String) {
    auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] result, error in
        if result == nil, error != nil {
            self?.showAlert = true
        }
        else {
            guard result != nil, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            /* Success */
            self?.signedIn = true
        }
        
    }
}

Comment: Add `onSuccess` parameter to MyFunction as shown in the answer and use `MyFunction` as shown in the answer.

Comment: Added an alternative solution now, having more information about your model. Check it out.